# Zend Skeleton framework not displaying using Php

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I am working through the **ZEND Skeleton** installation described [here](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/)

I am running it on an Apache server (in my home network) on Ubuntu 16.10

When I switched off the server yesterday the installation was working correctly, and displaying the expected Zend pages, as per the documentation.

To clarify - I need to know why the previously working installation on **Apache** has stopped rendering the pages in Php

I bookmarked these links in my browser. When I booted the server this morning and went to those links I get the result shown in the image below:-

Local browser URL (192.168.1.201/zendtest1/)

[Zend Skeleton index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBEIS.jpg)

It appears that in switching off and on the machine the Zend installation has stopped accessing Php to render out the page in the browser.

Does anyone have any experience of this, or any suggestion as to what may have occurred?

Answer (score 0):

The document root of a ZF2/ZF3 project is public, so you should use one of the strategies exposed in the quick start to either:

- set the proper document root on your server
- use the php development server
- use vagrant and a VM
- use docker

You could also access the address with typing `/public` at the end, that will probably not work at some point for your assets though. Then you will need to fix your basepath.